# Elegant calculation of array elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, sorting, nsmutablearray

I would like to do some calculations and comparisons inside my array

assuming my array is simple as:

```
NSMutableArray *array;   
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
```

What would be an **elegant and clever** way to check if a number repeats itself 2,3,4 or 5 times inside this array.
(looking for something smart and dynamic....)

Comment: There is no "**elegant and clever**" way of doing that.  You pretty much just have to loop through and count.

Comment: What is the range of numbers that are expected in your array? Any fixed range? How many different numbers can there be in your array? Any constraints?

Comment: Are there any limits on what the integers are (i.e. a range) or is it just any positive or negative int?

Comment: I was looking for something generic, but to make it simple:
numbers are 0 to 10 , max 10 numbers in array count.

And I don't believe there is no elegant solution, we just need to find it ;) - if you are going to present a long ugly if in if statement then don't, I can do it myself (and feel dirty and stupid all day long... )

Comment: @ShiShi A very short way: `NSUInteger count = [[NSCountedSet setWithArray:array] countForObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to loop through things yourself if you just want to know how many times each object shows up.  That bit is really easy:

```
NSMutableArray *array;   
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]]; 
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]; 

NSCountedSet *counts = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:array]

NSLog(@"%d", [counts countForObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]]); // logs 3

[array release];
[counts release];
```

Comment: Thats very elegant, now I know why I love Objective-c !
Sorry for asking, aren't we missing a release in the above code?

Comment: @ShiShi You need to release `array` and `counts` both when you don't need them anymore or you can use convenience constructors to create them.

Comment: sure, just wanted to have a clean answer above for others. thanks you just the same.

Comment: @ShiShi fine fine.... ;)  Although if you're compiling for GC or ARC, the `release` statements are unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

If the numbers are only in range 0 to 10 then you should have an array of 11 elements, named `counts`. The i<sup>th</sup> element in the array is the number of times `i` appears in the original array. Filling in the `count` array is straightforward: a single loop through your initial array (`a`), on each iteration increment `counts[a[i]]`.

The number `i` repeats itself `counts[i]` times. No **if**'s :)

Comment: interesting, can u kindly elaborate, perhaps with some sample code?

Comment: @ShiShi: I don't know objective-c, so I can't provide a code example. Which part of the algorithm did you not understand exactly?

Comment: na, i think i got it, it is elegant even if there is one "if" ;)
I am going to play with this idea and post a working code assuming i get it working (objective-c) for others to see/learn.
Thank you just the same, I like the idea already.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this counts as elegant in your mind, but you could always subclass NSMutableArray to add code that counts occurrences of specific numbers as they are added/removed. The documentation for NSMutableArray says that there is rarely a good reason to subclass it, but it does give examples of when it might make sense, including this one:

> Acquiring more information about what is happening to the collection (for example, statistics gathering).

I would consider what you are doing as a form of statistics gathering, wouldn't you?

Comment: yes, spot on when it comes to statistics and collection
Nevertheless, subclassing it seems like an overkill.

Comment: Well, if you wanted something that is reusable and encapsulates your code for easier reading, I wouldn't consider sub-classing "overkill."

Comment: sure, still Dave DeLong has posted a real nice one there.... I need to see how well it works with a large set of numbers, nevertheless it looks good , on that I hope you agree